# sql loader without .dat extension

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Oracle's sqlldr defaults to a `.dat` extension. That I want to override. I don't like to rename the file. When googled get to know few answers to use `.` like `data='fileName.'` which is not working. Share your ideas, please.

Error message is `fileName.dat is not found`.

Comment: "*Also tried with adding*" - what exactly did you try? What was the command you used? Also "*not working*" is not a valid error message from SQLLoader. **[edit]** your question and add the command that you used. Do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Why can't you simply specify the correct file extension in the control file?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, File has no extension. Also, not sure what do you mean by extension in control file. I only know INFILE that i am not using and instead sending as `sqlldr...... data=`fileName`

Comment: Can you confirm you're trying to do this on Linux/Unix, since the Windows-only `filename.` workaround isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Sqlloder has default extension for all input files data,log,control...

- `data= .dat`
- `log= .log`
- `control = .ctl`
- `bad =.bad`
- `PARFILE  = .par`

But you have to pass filename without apostrophe and dot

`sqlloder pass/user@db control=control data=data`

sqloader will add extension. `control.ctl data.dat`

Nevertheless i do not understand why you do not want to specify extension?

Comment: I will get a very big file from external system that I need to rename/copy just for the sake of adding an extension. Is there a way that we can say to sqlldr not to add `.dat` extension and go with the actual filename I have provided.

Comment: data='filename.' or data='filename.' it ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least in Unix/Linux environments. In Windows you can use the trailing period trick, specifying either `INFILE 'filename.'` in the control file or `DATA=filename.` on the command line. WIndows file name handling allows that; you can for instance do `DIR filename.` at a command prompt and it will list the file with no extension (as will `DIR filename`). But you can't do that with *nix, from a shell prompt or anywhere else.

You said you don't want to copy or rename the file. Temporarily renaming it might be the simplest solution, but as you may have a reason not to do that even briefly you could instead create a hard or soft link to the file which *does* have an extension, and use that link as the target instead. You could wrap that in a shell script that takes the file name argument:

```
# set variable from correct positional parameter; if you pass in the control
# file name or other options, this might not be $1 so adjust as needed
# if the tmeproary file won't be int he same directory, need to be full path
filename=$1

# optionally check file exists, is readable, etc. but overkill for demo
# can also check temporary file does not already exist - stop or remove

# create soft link somewhere it won't impact any other processes
ln -s ${filename} /tmp/${filename##*/}.dat

# run SQL*Loader with soft link as target
sqlldr user/password@db control=file.ctl data=/tmp/${filename##*/}.dat

# clean up
rm -f /tmp/${filename##*/}.dat
```

You can then call that as:

```
./scriptfile.sh /path/to/filename
```

If you can create the link in the same directory then you only need to pass the file, but if it's somewhere else - which may be necessary depending on why renaming isn't an option, and desirable either way - then you need to pass the full path of the data file so the link works. (If the temporary file will be int he same filesystem you could use a hard link, and you wouldn't have to pass the full path then either, but it's still cleaner to do so).

As you haven't shown your current command line options you may have to adjust that to take into account anything else you currently specify there rather than in the control file, particularly which positional argument is actually the data file path.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  I get a monthly download of reference data used in medical application and the 485 downloaded files don't have file extensions (@2gb).  Unless I can load without file extensions I have to copy the files with .dat and load from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31879955)